# Pipeline scheduled scripts in Google Apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, scheduled-tasks

I have two scripts Script_A and Script_B running underlying queries in Bigquery. I want to schedule Script_A using time scheduler (that I know) but I want Script_B to run when Script a successfully(or unsuccessfully will work as well) completes. Any way to make this event based trigger in Google Apps scripts?

Comment: Until someone provides an answer, I believe you can make use of the JS callback functionality to make sure you chain your actions. Normally in JS you would use promises for this case, but I am not sure it's an option for App Scripts.

Comment: Have a look at using Airflow or Cloud Composer instead of trying to do this with Apps Script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Scripts: How to call a function to run after another function is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051037/google-scripts-how-to-call-a-function-to-run-after-another-function-is-complete)